# add alpha channel to an image with PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

Having a transparent image 'img_rgb_pil' of size (505,503,4) which I want to crop 'circularly'. For this I'm using this function :

```
def to_circular_image(img_rgb_pil): 
   npImage=np.array(img_rgb_pil)
   h,w=img_rgb_pil.size

   # Create same size alpha layer with circle
   alpha = Image.new('L', img_rgb_pil.size,0)
   draw = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
   draw.pieslice([0,0,h,w],0,360,fill=255)

   # Convert alpha Image to numpy array
   npAlpha=np.array(alpha)

   # Add alpha layer to RGB
   npImage=np.dstack((npImage,npAlpha))

   # Save with alpha
   return Image.fromarray(npImage) **#<---- TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 5), |u1**
```

When calling this fuction, I'm getting this error "TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 5), |u1" . I understand that PIL cannot transform an array of size(x,y,5) to a PIL image. However I don't know how to make a crop circular on a transparent image.

Here is what I get with the answer below :

input image: [input transparent image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT8wu.png)
output image : [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EgAQ.png)

Any help please?

Comment: first, cropping means reducing a picture by making complete vertical or horizontal cuts. what you want could be described as giving a picture an alpha channel, or applying a mask. -- then, the dimension being 5 would indicate that you ALREADY have something with four channels... what do you wanna do with that 4th channel? discard? overwrite?

Comment: Your input image is 4-channels. Is it CMYK or RGBA or something else? If it's RGBA, then like Christoph says, what are we supposed to do with the existing alpha channel?

Comment: Sorry for the delay (still no improvements). @ChristophRackwitz, I don't know what to do with this channel. But since my input image is an RGBA (@Mark), obviously it has 4 channel. I think the problem is clear : my aim is to make a circular image from an RGBA image. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you seem to want to bother with Numpy for this. Create an alpha channel and put it in with `Image.putalpha()` and your work is complete.

**Start Image**

[image]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Load image, ensuring not palette and discarding any existing alpha
im = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGB')

# Get size
w, h = im.size

# Make circular alpha channel
alpha = Image.new('L', RGBA.size, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(alpha)
draw.pieslice([0,0,h,w],0,360,fill=255)

# Display it to check then push it into image
alpha.show()
im.putalpha(alpha)
```

**Alpha**

[image]

**Result Image**

[image]

Comment: I edited my question to show you that your proposal doesn't seem to work for a transparent input image

Comment: Please post your actual image - rather than a gnome-screenshot of it with a checkered background. The reason it doesn't work is exactly due to the 2 questions Christoph and I asked under your original post - what should be done with any existing alpha channel. It seems that discarding it was not the correct answer - it needs combining with the new one.

Comment: I edited with posting my actual image. You mean to combine alpha image with the 4th channel of the input image?