Drawing a circle around a png image using PIL
I am trying to put player headshots inside / mask a circle around.
However, I get a colour on the background rather than transparent. Does anyone have any idea how I might achieve this? PS. I don't know why the desired output has a shadow... I am not worried about having this!


Currently, this is the code that I have used.
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def crop_image(url):
    img = Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(f"{url}"))
    
    img = img.convert("RGBA")
    
    # Create a circular mask
    size = (min(img.size),) * 2
    mask = Image.new('L', size, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    draw.circle((size[0] // 2, size[1] // 2), radius=size[0] // 2, fill="white", outline="grey", width=5)

    # Apply the mask to the image
    img = img.crop((0, 0, size[0], size[1]))
    img.putalpha(mask)
    
    img.save(r"C:\Users\petersk\Desktop\output.png")
    
    return img

url = "https://static.www.nfl.com/image/private/t_person_squared_mobile/f_auto/league/icjfdfsncqlsqe49iujv"

crop_image(url)


Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70665820/2836621

The source image already has an alpha channel and those pixels where the alpha is set to make them transparent have a color associated with them. The greenish color you're seeing is part of the original image. Your mask is removing the transparent pixels (setting the alpha component to opaque) from the original image allowing the color to become visible.
You can show this by simply removing the alpha channel of the source image:
Image.open(urllib.request.urlopen(url)).convert("RGB").show()



OP wants Drawing a circle around a png image using PIL
